# Display the Form using Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

This is what I have got:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoginForm));
t.Start();
Thread.Sleep(7500);
t.Abort();
InitializeComponent();

public void LoginForm()
{
    Application.Run(new frmLoginForm());
}
```

How can I make the thread wait until the form closes before aborting the thread.

Comment: Is this in main method?

Comment: See [Thread.Join Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: wat this 'InitializeComponent()' is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ShowDialog`() method to display the form, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the MSDN

Or

Better to Declare Thread as public and only abort the Thread in the [form closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  event

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoginForm));
t.Start();

InitializeComponent();

public void LoginForm()
{
    LoginForm  frmLogin=new LoginForm();                
    DialogResult dr =  frmLogin.ShowDialogue();
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        t.Abort();
    }
}
```

and in the form closing event set the `DialogResult` property as

`this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;`

Comment: I have a problem where it says "the name t does not exist in the current context" and it points me to line t.Abort(). Is this because i didn't make the thread public as i am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: I ended up writing var frmLogin = new frmLoginForm() and  moving everything except the first line out of LoginForm() and put it under t.Start() and appended the line this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes; to form closing at it worked. Thanks very much for your answer and everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
var frmLogin = new FrmLogin();
if (frmLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  Application.Run(new frmMainForm());
}
```

and in you frmLogin if login is OK then set the from dialog result as DialogResult.OK

Answer (score 0):

Continuing SumeshK's solution, I will take lil different approach:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoginForm));
    t.Start(); 
    t.Join();   
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void LoginForm()
{
    LoginForm  frmLogin=new LoginForm();                
    frmLogin.ShowDialog();
}
```

The method `ShowDialog` itself will block your thread from terminating/finishing. This should work. But I doubt about the `InitializeComponent()` method. what is it for?